# 2nd ODE with mixed IVP and BVP, (ie.) y(0) and y'(L). How to solve?

Tags: numpy, ode

this is a 2nd ODE with boundaries that I'm trying to solve, but I can't figure out. It is a heat transfer problem. If you have insights, it would be very appreciable.

Basically, boundary problem, but with different location. One at 0 and the other at the end.

T(0) unknown, y'(0) is a func. of T(0.06), but T(0.06) is given.
**The key is how to connect the known value, T(0.06)=300, to solve the problem.**

y''=0, y(0)=t0, y'(0)=(4.82e-08*T0**4-208.0)/1.2, y(0.06)=300

I tried this code, but no luck.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dU_dx(U, x):
    return [U[1], 0]

#set initial values
y0 = T0
z0 = (4.82e-08*T0**4-208.0)/1.2    
U0 = [y0, z0]
yL = 300     # how do I use this boundary condition?

L=0.006
#solve 2nd ode
xs = np.linspace(0, L, 100)
Us = odeint(dU_dx, U0, xs)
ys = Us[:,0]

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("T")
plt.title("2nd ODE")
plt.plot(xs,ys);

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
g = interp1d(xs,ys)

T=g(0)    
print("Temp(at 0)=",T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely not an elegant code, but this is the way I get the answer I want. But please, feel free to pose if you know  better code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dU_dx(U, x):
    return [U[1], 0]

#Assume initial value
T0=292.75
y0 = T0
z0 = (4.82e-08*T0**4-208.0)/1.2    
U0 = [y0, z0]

L=0.06
xs = np.linspace(0, L, 100)
Us = odeint(dU_dx, U0, xs)
ys = Us[:,0]

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("T")
plt.title("2nd ODE")
plt.plot(xs,ys);

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
g = interp1d(xs,ys)

#Repeat until see T(0.06)=300
T0=g(L)     
print("Temp(0)=",T0)
```